# Coffeescript translation

Tags: coffeescript

If I have this javascript:

```
function I_did_something(){
  this.test.assertExists('#selector', 'exists');
}

casper.then(I_did_something);
```

The problem is that casper is using `call` to call the `then` method meaning that I cannot do something like this:

```
@I_did_something = ->
  @assertExists('#selector', 'exists')

casper.then @I_did_something
```

Because `this` does not refer to the global object.

Can anyone suggest how I would translate this into coffeescript without using the window object preferably?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [fat arrow (`=>`)](http://coffeescript.org/#fat_arrow) to bind the function to the current `this`:

```
@I_did_something = =>
  @assertExists('#selector', 'exists')
```

That has a similar effect to:

```
that = @
@I_did_something = ->
  that.assertExists('#selector', 'exists')
```

and I think that's what you're after.